# Is this conjecture by Hao Wang proven?

Tags: reference-request, quasiperiodic-function

In [this link](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath540/kmath540.htm), where aperiodic tilings are discussed, the author mentions the following statement

> Interestingly, five years before Berger's proof, Hao Wang proved that
> there would be an algorithm for deciding whether a given set of tiles
> can tile the plane if every set of tiles that tile the plane also tile
> the plane periodically

Or in other words the quote claims Wang proved that
$$\nexists \text{ aperiodic tiling}\implies \text{the domino problem is decidable}$$
where the domino problem is asking the question whether a given set of Wang tiles can tile the plane.

I think I have seen this being posed as a conjecture but I am not sure so my question is whether Wang has proven this or only conjectured this. I also want to know if this goes both ways (is the $\implies$ a $\iff$?)

Comment: In a german website , Joerg Resag mentioned this problem and said that the periodic version is decidable (not formulated as a conjecture!) The general version is know to be undecidable (it can be reduced to the halting problem). Hence you actually can replace "$\implies$" by "$\iff$".

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot!